# Twitter and spam control

Tags: twitter

We are developing a carpool app, and are posting all search requests by customers and all registration requests by customers on twitter. There may be a time when the tweets will increase significantly. Do we need to do anything to ensure that we are not breaking any rules ? The tweet looks like this

The tweet looks someone like this

> @carEgiri ride from Viman Nagar, to Hindjewadi,. Install carEgiri Android app, and help reduce @pune_traffic? Thanks @mCruiseOn

`@carEgiri` and `@mCruiseOn` are our `@` tags. `@pune_traffic` is not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking the rules and policies for Twitter applications (https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms) and if you're unsure, file a ticket for the Platform Operations team at https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform